# Is the Classmember of type int is also public and final?

Tags: java

Please have a look on the following code.

```
   public class A
{
int classmemberi;

  public static void main(String args[])
   {
    int methodmemberi;

   }

  public int method1()
   {
    return 0;
   }
}
```

I'm using "javap -constants A" in windows 7 command prompt to know the static final constants in the program. The output screen is as follows.

```
G:\Sun\temp>javap -constants A
Compiled from "A.java"
public class A {
int classmemberi;
public A();
public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
```

public int method1(); 
   }

G:\Sun\temp>

So, From this output can i conclude that all classmember of type int are final and public.
Furthermore method1() is not declared as static but it is shown in the output. please guide me in this regard.

Thanking you

Comment: Take some time to format your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstand what `-constants` does.

It produces *additional* output for static final constants, but the "normal" output is still there.

So all the other stuff is not necessarily static or final.